# Group by Foreign Key and select (LINQ)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have 2 table:

> Table1: Id_tb1 (PK), Title1.
>
> Table2: Id_tb2 (PK), Id_tb1 (FK),Title2.

So the simple query of table2 can be written like this:

```
from p in table2 select new { p.Id_tb2, Title1 = p.Table1.Title1 }
```

How can I get Title1 in my Select when use group by FK column? something like this:

```
from p in table2 group p by p.Id_tb1 into g select g.Table1.Title1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result =
    from p in table2
    group p by p.Table1 into g
    select g.Key.Title1;
```

This groups by the `Table1` entity instead of just the id.

`g.Key` allows you to access the group key which is the `Table1` entity for each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var result = from p in table2 group p.Table1.Title1 by p.Id_tb1 into g select g.ToList();
```

This query is going to return a list of `Title1` per each group.

If you need to select more than one property then do this:

```
var result = from p in table2 group p by p.Id_tb1 into g select g.Select(e=>new { e.Id_tb2, Title1 = e.Table1.Title1 });
```